# How do I install security updates in Ubuntu

Tags: security

I get the following message during a login. How do I install security updates in Ubuntu.
Why am I getting the reboot error.

132 packages can be updated.
68 updates are security updates.

```
Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest
  http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud
*** /dev/xvda1 will be checked for errors at next reboot ***
```